# Explain why it is necessary why $M$ and $N$ are subspaces, not subsets, in this question

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working off of a set of notes on multilinear algebra http://web.pdx.edu/~erdman/ELMA/

I'm having trouble with the following exercise 2.6.5.  Show that there exists subsets $M$,$N$ which are not subspaces of $V$ such that

$$ (M + N)^{\perp}  \neq M^{\perp} \cap N^{\perp} $$

Where $M^{\perp} = \{ f \in V^* \mid f(x) = 0 \mbox{ for all }x \in M \}$.

Comment: What is the definition of $M+N$ for subsets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $A+B=\{\,a+b\mid a\in A,b\in B\,\}$, this may fail if one of the subsets $M,N$ does not contain$~0$, so that $M\cup N\not\subseteq M+N$. For instance if $x$ is any nonzero vector, consider $M=\{x\}$, $N=\{-x\}$. Or $M=V$ and $N=\emptyset$, for which $M+N=\emptyset$. For general subsets one does  have $(M + N)^\perp \supseteq M^\perp \cap N^\perp$.